# Wordpress draft & pending posts not showing

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have third party authors and they cannot publish posts - they have to submit them for review and I then review & publish them.

The posts are tied together & associated with each other, in a course>lesson>topic manner. In the backend, theres an 'associated content' meta box which shows the related posts in that course>lesson>topic structure.

Because the posts aren't fully published, they are not appearing in the 'associated content' meta box. This makes it impossible for the author to see the structure of their course.

Is there a way to get this 'associated content' meta box to pick up the unpublished/draft/pending posts?

The code I am dealing with is:

```
function learndash_course_navigation_admin_box() {
$post_types = array('sfwd-courses', 'sfwd-lessons', 'sfwd-quiz', 'sfwd-topic'); foreach( $post_types as $post_type ) {
    add_meta_box( 'learndash_course_navigation_admin_meta', __( 'Associated Content', 'learndash' ), 'learndash_course_navigation_admin_box_content', $post_type, 'side', 'high' );
}}add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'learndash_course_navigation_admin_box' );
```

Can anyone offer a snippet to add to functions.php to modify the query?

Thanks very much

Answer (score -1):

In `WP_Query($args)` of 'associated content' meta box, add:

`post_status' => array('publish', 'pending')`

to `$args` string. 
Normally, the value `'post_status'` set to `'publish'`, it means wordpress only show pulished post. To show both publish and pending post, you must redefine 'post_status' in your `WP_Query($args)`

Comment: Hi - I have updated the question with the actual source PHP that creates the meta box. Do you think you could help me with a snippet for my functions.php file? Thanks so much, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

You can add post_status to your query, the string 'any' will return all posts no matter the status,

```
  $args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'post',
                  'orderby'   => 'title',
                  'order'     => 'ASC',
                  'post_status' => 'any',

                );
```

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

`post_status` here you specify as single or array format.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters

Comment: `'post_status' => 'any'` means all post from post array.

Comment: Hi @Vasim Vanzara then you can answer that is  your busineess, I can also do like that.

Comment: make it proper way its community it important to make it perfect as much as possible.

Comment: Repeat a same answer it not worthy.Its not all about point and score.be productive.

Comment: As you wish if you want to add code any you can anyone else make it correct.

Comment: I also Repeat a same answer, you can answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128059/discussion-between-samyappa-and-vasim-vanzara).

Comment: Hi - I have updated the question with the actual source PHP that creates the meta box. Do you think you could help me with a snippet for my functions.php file? Thanks so much, I really appreciate it.